# How do I read a CSV file for my Map Reduce job using Hadoop Streaming?I am using Python for my Map reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I read a CSV file for a python based Map reduce job in Hadoop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Hadoop in python to process a large csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255973/using-hadoop-in-python-to-process-a-large-csv-file)

Comment: Have a look at [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255973/using-hadoop-in-python-to-process-a-large-csv-file). This would give you a fair idea to proceed.
Also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038720/using-files-in-hadoop-streaming-with-python) would give you a question similar to your.